# BATのFORでリストを取得するときの並び順について

Tags: batch-file

すいません質問のタイトル及び本文の日本語が所々可笑しいかもしれません。

```
FOR %%i IN (*.jpg) DO ( ~ )
```

とした時、実際に存在する画像の名前が

```
1.jpg,2.jpg...9.jpg,10.jpg
```

この様な場合、処理の順番が

```
1.jpg > 10.jpg > 2.jpg ... 9.jpg
```

となってしまうのですがこれを名前順(表示)に処理することは可能ですか？

Comment: 簡単にはできないと思います。標準のコマンドだけではおそらく無理です。SORTやDIRのオプションを調べてみましたが数値部分だけに着目して並べ替えるものはありませんでした。※bashをインストールすればなんとかなります

Comment: bashをインストールしてもいいですが、わりと標準で入っているPowerShellで処理する方が環境構築の負荷がないためおすすめします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。名前を0で埋めて書き出してから処理する方法を少し考えましたが、順番そのものが変えられるならその方が良いと思い質問しました。ご指摘通りPowerShellを使った処理を考えてみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

単純に`数値.txt`を数字順にソートするだけならば[teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/101231)の回答や後述のバッチファイル(`test.bat`)でソートできます。

しかしコードが複雑で流用しにくいものになりがちです。
私もPowershellの使用をおすすめします。

#### テスト用フォルダにサンプルファイルを書き出すスクリプト

回答の結果を例示するための下準備用Powershellスクリプトです。
無視して構いません。

```
# 下準備(ファイル作成)
$numArr = @(1, 2, 4, 10, 200)
foreach($num in $numArr) {
    $num >> "$num.txt"
    $num >> "prefix_$num.txt"
}
```

#### test.bat

このバッチファイルでは数字をインクリメントしてファイルが存在する場合は表示することで疑似ソートしています。
ファイルの桁数が大きいとそこそこ遅いです。

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem ファイル名の最大値取得
set max=0
for %%f in (???.txt) do (
    if %%~nf gtr !max! set max=%%~nf
)

rem 数字をインクリメントしてヒットする場合は表示
for /l %%i in (1, 1, %max%) do (
    set f=%%i.txt
    if exist !f! (echo !f!)
)
```

> 1.txt
>   2.txt
>   4.txt
>   8.txt
>   10.txt
>   200.txt

#### Powershell

`接頭辞+数字`を含むファイル名の有無に応じて、様々な方法で簡単にソートできるコードを例示します。

```
# ファイル名が数字のみ抽出してソート
ls | where BaseName -match "^\d+$" | sort { [int]$_.BaseName } | select Name
```

> 1.txt
>   2.txt
>   4.txt
>   8.txt
>   10.txt
>   200.txt

```
# ファイル名から固定文字数削除(ここでは"prefix_"の7文字)して数字を切り出してソート
ls | where { $_.BaseName.StartsWith("prefix_") } | sort { [int]$_.BaseName.SubString(7) } | select Name
```

> prefix_1.txt
>   prefix_2.txt
>   prefix_4.txt
>   prefix_8.txt
>   prefix_10.txt
>   prefix_200.txt

```
# ファイル名から数字を正規表現で取り出してその次に普通のファイル名でソート
ls | sort { [int]($_.Name -replace "\D", "") }, Name | select Name
```

> 1.txt
>   prefix_1.txt
>   2.txt
>   prefix_2.txt
>   4.txt
>   prefix_4.txt
>   8.txt
>   prefix_8.txt
>   10.txt
>   prefix_10.txt
>   200.txt
>   prefix_200.txt

```
# 上記の逆に数字以外→数字順にソート
ls | sort { $_.Name -replace "\d", "" }, { [int]($_.Name -replace "\D", "") } | select Name
```

> 1.txt
>   2.txt
>   4.txt
>   8.txt
>   10.txt
>   200.txt
>   prefix_1.txt
>   prefix_2.txt
>   prefix_4.txt
>   prefix_8.txt
>   prefix_10.txt
>   prefix_200.txt